# What is the best programming language to get started with?

Tags: programming-languages

I'm trying to get into programming, so I thought I would ask for the opinions of avid programmers. What is a good language for beginners, with a good trajectory to more difficult/in-demand languages? I tried C, but it was quite hard, so maybe something a bit easier.

Comment: I'd recommend trying C but ignore pointers in the beginning. Buy an Arduino and do simple projects (yes, I know they say the language they use is called "wiring" but it's actually just C++ with an auto-generated `main()` function). Once you are comfortable with variables and functions then move on to trying to understand pointers.

Comment: Thank you @slebetman ! I have  arduino so I can try that

Comment: One thing to remember that most experienced programmers will almost never tell you: nobody knows the entire language regardless of what language you learn. Most people use a subset of the language regularly and need to look at documentation (or these days google) when they hit some feature they rarely use (or have never used before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say to start with Python. It's very multi-purpose, and has a lot of scalability. Also, please refrain from posting questions asking for opinions.

Comment: Are there any aolternatives, maybe something for websites?

Comment: @userQWERTY123456, you could always start with learning the HTML-CSS-JS trifecta, focusing on the basics and moving outwards. I recommend watching a few YouTube tutorial series on building simple websites.